# SDWebImage crash randomly

Tags: ios, crash, sdwebimage

Im using SDImage in my project, when checking the crash log, this SDImage crashed at 
`[SDWebImageDownloaderOperation start]` func, here are logs, pls help, it wastes my 2 days.

Thread 12:

```
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3c383eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20

1 CoreFoundation 0x34143045 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 129

2 CoreFoundation 0x34141da3 __CFRunLoopRun + 883

3 CoreFoundation 0x340b4ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357

4 CoreFoundation 0x340b4d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105

5 demo 0x0022a683 -[SDWebImageDownloaderOperation start] + 471

6 Foundation 0x34a73be3 __block_global_6 + 103

7 libdispatch.dylib 0x3c2ae11f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 11

8 libdispatch.dylib 0x3c2b2961 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 253

9 libdispatch.dylib 0x3c2b2ac1 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 85

10 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3c2e2a11 _pthread_wqthread + 361
```

another log

Thread 9 Crashed:

```
0 CoreFoundation 0x35418b9c CFEqual + 24

1 CFNetwork 0x34d60469 URLConnectionClient::getRequestForTransmission(unsigned char, CFURLResponse*, _CFURLRequest const*, __CFError**) + 205

2 CFNetwork 0x34cc666d URLConnectionClient::_clientWillSendRequest(_CFURLRequest const*, _CFURLResponse*, URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue*) + 157

3 CFNetwork 0x34cc64c5 URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo*, long) + 457

4 CFNetwork 0x34cc61a3 URLConnectionClient::processEvents() + 107

5 CFNetwork 0x34cc60d9 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 157

6 CoreFoundation 0x354a3ad3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION_ + 15

7 CoreFoundation 0x354a329f __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 215

8 CoreFoundation 0x354a2045 __CFRunLoopRun + 653

9 CoreFoundation 0x354254a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301

10 CoreFoundation 0x3542536d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105

11 demo 0x001d1683 -[SDWebImageDownloaderOperation start] + 471

12 Foundation 0x34fe2793 __block_global_6 + 103

13 libdispatch.dylib 0x3435cc59 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 13

14 libdispatch.dylib 0x3435f817 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 259

15 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3288cdfb _pthread_wqthread + 295
```

another crash on cancel

Thread 0 Crashed:

```
0 demo 0x001a58f2 -[SDWebImageDownloaderOperation cancel] + 130

1 demo 0x001a88df -[SDWebImageCombinedOperation cancel] + 179

2 demo 0x001aaf71 -[UIImageView(WebCache) cancelCurrentImageLoad] + 49
```

my log help~

Comment: Perhaps you can share your code that uses the SDWebImage objects.

Comment: Someone suggested rolling back to an earlier version: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/414#issuecomment-22639141 I tried that but was getting even more crashes.